# How can I sum values within a specific time and date range?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to work out which formula to use for summing values within a period of time and date. I have the following data:

```
A                B             C

Jan 1, 2011      8:00 AM       10

Jan 1, 2011      10:00 PM      15

jan 2, 2011      8:30 AM       20

Jan 2, 2011      9:00 AM       15

Jan 3, 2011      8:25 AM       11

Jan 3, 2011      9:00 PM       10
```

I need to add all values in column C which correspond to a certain date and time interval, say, `Jan 1, 2011 9:00 AM to Jan 3, 9:00 AM`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 8):

You'll need to use `SUMPRODUCT` instead of `SUMIF` since you need to satisfy multiple criteria/conditions for the sum.

Assuming the values in column **A** are dates and not strings, this is the formula you need:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((dates+times>=start_date+start_time)*values_to_add)-SUMPRODUCT((dates+times>end_date+end_time)*values_to_add)
```

Here it is in action, using the data range you provided as an example:

[image]

If you merge columns **A** & **B**, you'll only need a shorter formula than the one I previously mentioned. You could also use Excel's **Advanced Filtering** tool and then obtain a subtotal of the filtered cells.

Comment: nice! I didn't know about array formulas! +1

Comment: Generally, one of the advantages of SUMPRODUCT is that you don't have to use array formulas.  It can handle ranges like an array formula, very powerful.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a subtotal cell at the end of column c, then create a table out of your data, and filter using only the dates you want. =sumif() is probably faster, but may be less flexible in the end.

Answer (score 1):

This will work without an array formula, letting I1 be the earlier date, and J1 be the later date:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A6+B1:B6 >= I1)*(A1:A6+B1:B6 <= J1)*C1:C6)
```

If you want to use an array formula, then you can just use a SUM:

```
{=SUM(IF((A1:A6+B1:B6 >= I1)*(A1:A6+B1:B6 <= J1),C1:C6,0))}
```

but I'd never use an array if I didn't need to.

Comment: Great! +1 for providing a shorter formula. You were right about SUMPRODUCT not needing arrays too.

Comment: Is there any way to make this work when the table may contain empty rows? I get a #VALUE error if I add an empty row to my table.