# Count negative values within date range (month)

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, worksheet-function

I have values in a table like this

```
Date    Values
01/01    5:35
02/01   -7:08
02/01    3:45
15/01   -4:05
02/02    3:25
13/02    4:25
19/02    6:20
```

I would like to count by month how many 'Values' are negative (i.e. contain a '-' character). I have tried a few things without success. Assume that the values in 'Date' column are real dates so I can use functions like month(). The values in 'Values' column are text (i.e. prefaced with ') as I can't get Excel to cope with negative times correctly.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A9999<>""),--(MONTH(A2:A9999)=1),IF("-*",B2:B9999))
```

I was hoping this [How can I sum values within a specific time and date range?](https://superuser.com/questions/297984/how-can-i-sum-values-within-a-specific-time-and-date-range) would help, but I couldn't adapt it for my circumstance.

Appreciate some advice.

Comment: For absolute clarity, I would use this formula for each month. The code example above is for January and the desired result is 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use wildcards when comparing with = so you need LEFT function in SUMPRODUCT formula like this

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(A2:A9999<>""),--(MONTH(A2:A9999)=1),--(LEFT(B2:B9999)="-"))`

That will count January dates in any year

In Excel 2007 it might be easier with COUNTIFS, assuming you have the start date of the month to count in D2 (e.g. 1/1/2012) then use this formula for January 2012 only

`=COUNTIFS(A:A,">="&D2,A:A,"<="&EOMONTH(D2,0),B:B,"-*")`

Comment: The countif function looks really promising, but for some reason it's not counting on dates which are at the end of the month (eg. 31/01/2012). Which is really bizzare since we are using >= and <=

Comment: I can get it to work with 
  =COUNTIFS(A:A,">="&D2,A:A,"<="&EOMONTH(D2,0)+1) 
but it seems really weird

Comment: If column has has dates `and times` (times possibly not displayed but still present) then that won't count the last day - +1 will include those but then you should remove the = and use just < otherwise it could count dates beyond end of month, i.e. =COUNTIFS(A:A,">="&D2,A:A,"<"&EOMONTH(D2,0)+1,B:B,"-*")

Comment: Yes I thought about this on the bus home. I do have time data in these fields. I guess EOM is returning 31/01 00:00 not 31/01 23:59, so I can use EOMONTH(D2,0)+TIME(23,59,59). 
Thanks, this is what I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

To **count negative values** you can use `=COUNTIF(A1,"-*")`

To count for a *specific month* `=IF(MONTH(B1)=1,COUNTIF(A1,"-*"),0)` this will put a 1 for any negative value for `month=1` (january). You can change the `month = value` for your month and you will get a column of 1s and 0s when you drag it down `column C` (helper column)

At the end of the helper column you can `=sum(C:C)` to **count the number of negative values for a given month**

of if you want to calculate the sum of the negative values `=SUMIF(C:C,"=1",A:A)`

Basically, what we're doing is using a *helper column* in `column C`. You can hide this column and do your `=sumif` or `=if` somewhere in `Column D` if you don't want the *helper column* to show.

### edit

Changed the `countif` to count if it has a minus sign in it as the <0 won't work for non-numbers - should work

Comment: Thanks, sorry I wasn't clear why I was using if("-*",cellref) is that the data comes from an data import with values like '-1:48', '4:13' etc. I may have to transform this data to make my life easier.

Comment: Also, unless I'm missing something this would mean I need 12 'helper columns' for each month? Ok, I guess it works but I was hoping for some elegant solution. Realise this is not always possible, so appreciate your input.

Comment: @aland you can use the same helper column for each month, just when you get your count or sum, `copy - special paste - values` to another column with a label.

Comment: @aland Also I'm a bit confused on your first comment, would you clarify your question in regards to that, we may be able to manipulate this solution :)

Comment: Ok I've clarified my initial question. Sorry I guess my first edit for  'absolute' clarity was a bit ambitious :D

Comment: @aland what part of my solution doesn't work for you?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2698/discussion-between-raystafarian-and-aland)

Comment: Thanks for your help but I couldn't work out how I could use your formula without having 12 'helper' columns for each month of the year.